# Qt: How should I route a signal to the appropriate object dynamically?

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing an application in Qt. I am trying to create a system of signals and slots to connect a single controller thread to multiple threads which represent real-life devices. The number of devices is known at compile-time, but I would like it to be as easy as possible to change the number of them. My initial approach used templates on the signals, something like this:

```
signals:
    template<int whichOne> void updateDoohickeyState(dooHickeyState newState);
```

My hope was that I could then connect these to the devices like so:

```
connect(doohickeyController, doohickeyController::updateDoohickeyState<0>,
        doohickeys[0], doohickeyObject::updateState,
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

connect(doohickeyController, doohickeyController::updateDoohickeyState<1>,
        doohickeys[1], doohickeyObject::updateState,
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
// Etc...
```

Then, when I wanted to signal a device, I could do something like:

```
emit updateDoohickeyState<0>(doohickeyState);
emit updateDoohickeyState<1>(anotherDoohickeyState);
```

Unfortunately, Qt's MOC does not support templates on signals and slots; therefore, this does not work.

So, how else can I implement this? I have one controller which needs to signal to particular one of multiple identical devices in other threads. I would ideally like to do so without adding more signals (more complicated to update later), filtering slot-side (inefficient) or adding another class in the middle.

Comment: Have you take a look at QSignalMapper?

Comment: QSignal mapper is marked as obsolete in Qt 5.12. Also, it seems to solve the inverse of my problem: one receiver and many senders. I have one object that needs to signal to many other objects, but direct that signal to only one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke an object's slot directly using QMetaObject::invokeMethod instead of connected signal emission. Like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(doohickeys[0], "updateState", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(dooHickeyState, doohickeyState));
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(doohickeys[1], "updateState", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(dooHickeyState, anotherDoohickeyState));
```

Comment: Probably a macro would help: #define UPDATE_STATE(obj, arg) QMetaObject::invokeMethod((obj), "updateState", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(dooHickeyState, (arg)));

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want a [pub/sub service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).  It's quite easy to implement it in Qt using signals/slots and and a Q_Object for the service.